# HDMI sound not detected when plugging/unplugging from external monitor

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, hdmi, 19.10

I am using laptop(Legion Y530) on it is Ubuntu 19.10 and every time I plug/unplug an HDMI cable the HDMI sound is not present in the Sound Settings. Only way to fix this is to restart pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Is there a way that I can fix this permanently and not restarting pulseaudio everytime HDMI is plugged?

Comment: perhaps a tweak

https://extensions.gnome.org/#

Sound Input & Output Device Chooser

gives a top bar right corner option for sound volume and device.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have exactly the same issue in Debian 10 Buster